# AngularJS S3 file upload - Policy Condition failed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to S3 using ng-file-upload module. I'm getting an error:

> Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq",
>   "$succes_action_status", "201"]

My code is based on this [particular example](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/wiki/Direct-S3-upload-and-Node-signing-example), slightly changed:

**api.js:**

```
exports.signing = function(req, res) {

var request = req.body;
var fileName = request.filename;
var path = fileName;

var readType = "public-read";

var expiration = moment().add(5, 'm').toDate();

var s3Url = process.env.S3_URL;

var s3Policy = {
    'expiration': expiration,
    'conditions': [{
        'bucket' : process.env.S3_BUCKET,
    },
    ['starts-with', '$key', path],
    {
        'acl': readType
    },
    {
        'succes_action_status': '201'
    },
    ['starts-with', '$Content-Type', request.type],
    ['content-length-range', 2048, 10485760],
    ]
};

var stringPolicy = JSON.stringify(s3Policy);
var base64Policy = new Buffer(stringPolicy, 'utf-8').toString('base64');

//sign policy
var signature = crypto.createHmac('sha1', process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY).update(new Buffer(base64Policy, 'utf-8')).digest('base64');

var credentials = {
    url: s3Url,
    fields: {
        key: fileName,
        AWSAccessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
        acl: readType,
        policy: base64Policy,
        signature: signature,
        'Content-Type': request.type,
        success_action_status: '201'
    }
};

res.jsonp(credentials);
};
```

**controller.js**

```
$scope.upload = function(files) {
    if (files.length > 0) {
        var filename = files[0].name;
        var type = files[0].type;
        var query = {
            filename: filename,
            type: type
        }
    };

    if (files && files.length) {
        for (var i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            photoService.signingS3(query).success(function(result) {
                Upload.upload({
                url: "https://***.s3.amazonaws.com",
                method: "POST",
                fields: result.fields,
                transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
                        //Headers change here
                        var headers = headersGetter();
                        delete headers['Authorization'];
                        return data;
                },
                file: file
            }).progress(function(evt) {
                console.log('progress: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'is uploaded successfully. Response: ' + data);
                }).error(function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
            });
            }

        }
    }
```

Can you tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: there is a problem with your s3 policy, when trying to sign in & upload, please check again the var s3Policy

Answer (score 0):

here `['starts-with', '$key', path]`  the value of path must be: 'somedirectory in s3' + fileName; . Also, check your bucket name is filled accordingly.

Comment: I did create a "test" directory in my bucket and it didn't work out. Now i get `Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["starts-with", "$key", "test/iphone.jpg"]`